# Solve system of PDES

Tags: pde

I need to solve the following system of partial differential equations

> \begin{align}
> \psi_{x} &= -i a \psi - b \phi,\quad &(1)\\
> \phi_{x} &= b \psi + i a \phi,\quad &(2)\\
> \psi_{t} &= - ic \psi + d \phi, \quad &(3)\\
> \phi_{t} &= - d \psi + i c \phi, \quad &(4)
> \end{align}

where $\psi=\psi(x,t),\; \phi=\phi(x,t)$ and $\psi_{x} $ means derivative w.r.t $x$ and $a,\;b,\;c,\;d$ are constants. How to solve (1)-(4)?

Comment: Do you need an algebraic or numerical solution? Does it have to be with Maple? Also: I think you have a system of PDEs because you have two derivates (x and t)

Comment: @ Grimes, I need algebraic solution

Comment: In that case, this question my be off-topic in this site. To help you in the solution, you can check that you can rewrite your system as $\partial/\partial x \mathbf
{\Psi} = A B^{-1} \partial/\partial t \mathbf{\Psi}$.

Comment: How can you solve a system of PDEs without boundary conditions?

Comment: For example when we solve equation (1) then the constant appear can be evaluated from equation (3).

Comment: The you're not solving the system of PDEs, you're just substitiuting for the constants to get a more complex system of pdes.